# Modifying only node forms, not forms appearing in blocks?

Tags: nodes, blocks, forms

I have a contact webform in a block in a sidebar that appears on every page.

I also have some webform nodes.

I want to use `hook_form_alter()` to modify the forms that are nodes, not those that appear in blocks.

How can I differentiate between the two in code?

Comment: Is it ONLY webform forms that you need to alter? And how do you need to alter them?

Comment: You could single out the webform that's in a block (sounds like it's unique) by viewing it's form ID, and then in the hook_form_alter() check that form ID != webform's id.  Not including this as an answer because I'm not really sure if it's unique or not

Comment: No, it's not only webform forms that I need to alter. I need to alter them in various ways, depending on the type. Some will be completely rebuilt, and others will have entries processed before they're saved. I'd like to be able to exclude any and all forms in blocks in case the user adds a new one later.

Comment: You can also, if you have multiple forms that need to be altered in the same way, use [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using hook_form_formID_alter()**

You could use `hook_form_formID_alter()` to target this [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) node specifically.

For example:

```
function hook_form_webform_client_form_429_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // Alterations here.
}
```

webform_client_form_429 in this example is found using the `<form id=''>` from the node in the block you want to alter.

**Using hook_form_alter for all Webforms rendered in a block**

If the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) block was created using [webform_block_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.module/function/webform_block_view/7)() then $form['#node']->webform_block should be TRUE.  Pages on the other hand should be `$form['#node']->webform_block == FALSE`

Try using [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)() from the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) project to poke around the $form variable for webform_block specific items.

My assumption would be that you could use:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form['#node']->webform_block == FALSE) {
      // Alterations
   }
}
```